# How to add a field that link to attachment model?

Tags: hyperlink, odoo, attachment

I have to include a field (paper) to store files in my model (salary) that looks like a hyperlink like if it was a binary. But I don't want it to be a binary stored in my model but to be stored in attachment model as an attachment.
In Knowledge module you can see that it is done, but it is done on itself, as Knowledge is the very module where attachments are stored.
I need to link from my model to attachment model so as the file will be stored in that model but in my model I have to have a field that looks like a hyperlink and when I link on it, I can download the file. As the same time, my field has to behave as a binary field, as I have to load files from it.
It has to work in version 7 and 8

Answer (score 0):

if someone still need it here is the original xml code to create the 'attachment' submenu in 'others' button:

```
 <record model="ir.values" id="ir_action_document_file_directory_form">
     <field name="key2" eval="'tree_but_open'"/>
     <field name="model" eval="'document.directory'"/>
     <field name="name">Browse Files</field>
     <field name="value" eval="'ir.actions.act_window,%d'%action_document_file_directory_form"/>
 </record>
```

it is in

> addons\document\document_view.xml

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this works for you:

adding another field to create the link

```
file = fields.Binary("your_file", related='ir.attachment.datas')
```

Comment: Programme, what do you mean with "your_file" parameter? what would it be?

Comment: "you_file" is just the string that would be shown if you displayed it.